# Swift performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: is unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

I have an app in Objective C that I'm transitioning to Swift. In Objective C, I have this method:

`[self.view performSelector:@selector(someSelector) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1f];`

I'm working with Swift and I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried:

`self.view.performSelector(Selector("someSelector"), withObject: self, afterDelay: 0.1)`

Here's the error that I get: `'performSelector' is unavailable: 'performSelector' methods are unavailable`

What call would I use to call a method `afterDelay`?

**UPDATE**

Here's what I ended up with:

```
extension NSObject {

    func callSelectorAsync(selector: Selector, object: AnyObject?, delay: NSTimeInterval) -> NSTimer {

        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self, selector: selector, userInfo: object, repeats: false)
        return timer
    }

    func callSelector(selector: Selector, object: AnyObject?, delay: NSTimeInterval) {

        let delay = delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(selector, toTarget:self, withObject: object)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I would disagree. I'm not asking how to perform a Selector. I'm asking how to perform a Selector `afterDelay`

Comment: The same question is answered there.  Use GCD and dispatch_after or dispatch_async.

Comment: @David: It's not answered there. `dispatch_after` uses dispatch queues; whereas `performSelector:afterDelay:` uses the current run loop. They are different.

Comment: hello I used your code in my project, thought you might be interested: https://github.com/goktugyil/CozyLoadingActivity

Comment: self.perform(#selector(self.someSelector), with: self, afterDelay: 0.1)

Answer (score 166):

**Swift 4**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    // your function here
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(0.1)) {
    // your function here
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) 
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
    // your function here 
})
```

Comment: But this is different. `dispatch_after` works with dispatch queues. `performSelector:afterDelay:` and `NSTimer` work on run loops.

Comment: And your point is? GCD is perfectly suitable here...

Comment: You should pass _dispatch_time_t_ as first argument
`var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                // your function here
            })`

Comment: so if I want 3 seconds, I do 3.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)?

Comment: why is this dispatch_after better than NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval?  Aside from the type-safe issue of NSTimer's methods, dispatch_after is less intuitive and I don't know how to handle the "userInfo" scope within the dispatch_after as it does not take a data argument.

Comment: @mobibob you can just call your function with the userInfo as parameter within the dispatch block

Comment: In Swift 3 you do it like this... DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {   //  Stuff  }

Comment: for the latest swift this is the correct way to create dispatchTime: let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + 0.1

Comment: Here is what I use:
`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    //
}`

Comment: nice, but `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` doesn't work anymore.  Is there a way to cancel a scheduled dispatch before it runs?

Comment: @progrmr open a new question for that

Comment: "perform selector" had a possibility to cancel this scheduled task

Comment: Would `perform(#selector(myFunctionName), with: nil, afterDelay: 2.1)` be an option, with `@objc func myFunctionName() {...}` ?

Comment: your example doesn't allow to cancel requests but "perform selector" has such ability

Answer (score 112):

You could do this:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("someSelector"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func someSelector() {
    // Something after a delay
}
```

#### SWIFT 3

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(someSelector), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func someSelector() {
    // Something after a delay
}
```

Comment: Just a note that this method only works if your class inherits from an NSObject or derivative class.  It won't work in a pure swift class.

Comment: @JasonCrump: It will work as long as the method is marked `@objc` or `dynamic`

Comment: Note that this only directly translates for methods with no arguments. If they take one argument, they will be passed the `NSTimer` in this case, not the given object as in `performSelector:afterDelay:`. Also, the method cannot return anything.

Comment: Also, note that this method will not work on threads without a run loop-- i.e. GCD background threads.

Comment: hello I used your code in my project, thought you might be interested: https://github.com/goktugyil/CozyLoadingActivity

Comment: To cancel operation of timer thread, i tried as "timer.invalidate()" in swift2. Here "timer" is a variable. Try as follows                                                   func stopBackgroundTimer() {
        guard let timerIsAlive = timer else {
            return
        }
        timerIsAlive.invalidate()
        return
    }                                                                                                             func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        stopBackgroundTimer()
        
    }

Comment: When I  used this method App crashes saying unidentified selector. It worked proper when I called method directly(self.<methodname>)

Comment: 1)you can use `Timer` instead of `NSTimer`; 2)if you call `scheduledTimer...` then you can use block and don't need to use "selector" and separate functions at all

Answer (score 10):

Swift is statically typed so the `performSelector:` methods are to fall by the wayside.

Instead, use GCD to dispatch a suitable block to the relevant queue — in this case it'll presumably be the main queue since it looks like you're doing UIKit work.

EDIT: the relevant `performSelector:` is also notably missing from [the Swift version of the `NSRunLoop` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/index.html) ("1 Objective-C symbol hidden") so you can't jump straight in with that. With that and its absence from the Swiftified `NSObject` I'd argue it's pretty clear what Apple is thinking here.

Comment: That's a problem. `dispatch_get_current_queue` is deprecated, and obtaining a queue to run on the current thread (w/ runloop) is not as easy. The `performSelector:` methods have their place and they are not going anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem here — he wants the selector to perform on `self.view`. So it's probably UIKit work. So it goes on the main queue. Otherwise I guess you'd need to throw in the `@objc` attribute to force a selector despite Swift, and then probably you'd be smart to use `NSRunLoop` directly but you could inherit from `NSObject` to get the old `performSelector`s.

Comment: My comment was more on your comment, not the question. If after all, `performSelector:` is artificially disabled, a simple Objective C category wrapper will do.

Comment: Having followed-up on that, it's notably omitted from the Swift versions of the documentation `NSRunLoop` and from `NSObject`. I really think Apple wants this feature gone. So, yes, the workaround is fairly trivial for now but based on Apple's usual behaviour I'd argue it's not a pattern to endorse.

Comment: Endorsement and necessity are two different things.

Comment: +1 from me for that, but with the caveat that relying on something Apple wants rid of is likely to buy you quite a bit more necessary work in the future when the feature is eventually pulled away. If even Adobe and Microsoft can have Carbon pulled out from under them (rumours were that a 64-bit version was ready but Apple simply decided not to ship it after years of warnings) then us hoi polloi shouldn't adopt the logic that obviously Objective-C will always be underneath.

Comment: @Tommy: what's "something Apple wants rid of"? performSelector? or runloops?

Comment: @newacct I'm speculating, I have no inside knowledge, but for now it's probably only safe to say `performSelector`; runloops are tied up with event scheduling, and especially network access. But you can easily imagine that they'll become a purely internal thing. And I give it five years before we'll be saying goodbye to Objective-C entirely. The Java bridge didn't last that long and if the hype is right about Swift being suitable for systems programming we'll increasingly be talking about the bridge that allows Objective-C to access the system. Though, again, all speculation, not knowledge.

Comment: As of Xcode 7, the full family of performSelector methods are available in Swift, including `performSelectorOnMainThread()` and `performSelectorInBackground()`. Enjoy!

Comment: @FizzBuzz with the caveat that they work only on Objective-C classes (i.e. ones from genuine Objective-C and Swift classes that inherit by any route from NSObject) — otherwise you'll get a "class XXX does not implement methodSignatureForSelector:"