# How to execute a method in background in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out on Google, but I cannot find "How to execute a method in background in Swift".

Is there something similar to

```
performsSelectorInBackground:
```

from Objective-C?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[Because Swift is statically typed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170342/981049), there actually aren't selectors you can call.

[What you should be doing instead is Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](http://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     // do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both NSOperation and Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) are available in Swift. I would start by reading Apple's GCD and NSOperationQueue documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html