# How to add Admob interstitial ads

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob

I am trying to add a interstitial ad in a Swift SpriteKit game and most of the problems/soultions I see are related to the banner view and not the interstitial display of the admob ads.

What I did was adding all the frameworks and the sample code from google like described here [Adding interstitial ads to your project](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial#adding_interstitial_ads_to_your_project) into my GamveViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")

let request = GADRequest()
// Requests test ads on test devices.
request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
interstitial.loadRequest(request)
}
}
```

Then I want to call the function to display the ad in my GameScene.swift and this leads to an error and I dont know why

```
if (self.interstitialAd.isReady) {
                self.interstitialAd.presentFromRootViewController(self)

            }
```

The error codes I get are: 
1. "use of undeclared type "GADInerstittial"
2."GameScene has no member interstitial

It seems I need to connect my GameViewController and the Game Scene, but I do not know how. Anyone with a helping hand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216350/swift-interstitial-ad-on-viewdidload-admob/35218027#35218027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just present the ad in a gameScene, you need a viewController.

The easiest way is to put the code from GameScene into your ViewController.

So move/or create a func in ViewController like so

```
func showInterAd() {
   /// code to present inter ad
}
```

Than you can use something like NSNotificationCenter to forward the message from GameScene to the ViewController.

Still in your ViewController add an observer in viewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showInterAd), name: "ShowAd", object: nil)
```

Than in your GameScene when you want to show the ad post the notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ShowAd", object: nil)
```

Alternatively I have a helper on gitHub if you want a cleaner and more reusable solution

https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-iAds-AdMob-CustomAds-Helper

Comment: Thank you for your help - the notification center seems to solve my issues. since I am totally new to development in general and therefore also new to swift development - unfortunately I am not comfortable with the notification center. hope to find some good resource on it. You got any recommendations?

Comment: Hey, you are welcome. This should help https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-post-messages-using-nsnotificationcenter   Or  https://www.codebeaulieu.com/41/introduction-to-NSNotificationCenter-tutorial. Let me know how it goes